# decoder une chaine des characteres html,php,java,xml

Tags: java, php, html, xml

I am trying to build some code that contains a text input and a button. When I submit the form, I want to display a message.

My code works, but when I surpassed an average of 1000 lines, the program doesn't work and php displays this message

> Apache HTTP Server has stopped working

i want to Try to split the program on functions and change it to Optimize the

code

???

Here is what I have a do

```
if the first character is A and the second character is A 
    display "GROUP1-1"

else if the first character is A and the second character is B
    display "GROUP1-2"

else if the first character is A and the second character is C
    display "GROUP1-3"  

else if the first character is A and the second character is D
    display "GROUP1-4"

else if the first character is B and the second character is A
    display "GROUP2-1"

else if the first character is B and the second character is B
    display "GROUP2-2"

else if the first character is B and the second character is C
    display "GROUP2-3"
```

I am using Notepad++ and easyPHP.
This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>
exercice 
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
decoder ces caracteres 
<input type = "text" name ="t" size="8"/>
<input type ="submit" name ="decoder" value="Decoder">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['t']))
{
if(($_GET['t'][0]=='A')&&($_POST['t'][1]=='A')) {
echo "GROUP1-1"; 
}
else 
if(($_GET['t'][0]=='A')&&($_POST['t'][1]=='B')) {
echo "GROUP1-2"; 
}
else 
if(($_GET['t'][0]=='A')&&($_POST['t'][1]=='C')) {
echo "GROUP1-3"; 
}
if(($_GET['t'][0]=='A')&&($_POST['t'][1]=='D')) {
echo "GROUP2-1"; 
}
else 
if(($_GET['t'][0]=='B')&&($_POST['t'][1]=='A')) {
echo "GROUP2-1"; 
}
else 
if(($_GET['t'][0]=='B')&&($_POST['t'][1]=='B')) {
echo "GROUP2-2"; 
}
else 
if(($_GET['t'][0]=='B')&&($_POST['t'][1]=='C')) {
echo "GROUP2-3"; 
}
else
{ 
echo"erreur";
}
}
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing a `{` that goes with the last `else` in your if/elseif/else block.

Comment: Is that title supposed to be English?

Comment: hello Andreas 
you think that it's better to change the title to 
Decode a string of characters html, php, java, xml